# What is the difference between classic api and unified api ios project in xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the difference between classic api and unified api ios project in xamarin as mentioned in below screenshot?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

There is few difference between Classic API and Unified API:

1. Classic API does not support 64 bit applications.
2. Code sharing cumbersome.
3. Binary Reference:

   ```
   Classic API: monutouch

   Unified API: Xamarin.iOS
   ```
4. Architecture:

   ```
     Classic API: i386( for simulator), ARMV7 + ARMV7s + {ARMV&+ ARMV7s} for device

      Unified API: i386 , X86_64 , i386 + x86_64 (for simulator) + ARMV7 + ARMV7s + {ARMV&+ ARMV7s} + ARM64 + {ARMV7 + ARM64} + {ARMV7s + ARM64} + { ARMv7 + ARMv7s + ARm64} for device
   ```
5. Deployment Target(SDK Version default):

   ```
      Classic API:7.0

      Unified API: 8.0
   ```

Comment: Should *monutouch* be *monotouch*?

Answer (score 3):

Does this explain it?

> The new style API makes it easier than ever to share code between Mac and iOS as well as allowing you to support 32 and 64 bit applications with the same binary.

[Docs](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/newstyle/)